# appending function returns unexpected results, Dart

Tags: list, dart

this is the pyramid problem which is :
Write a function that when given a number >= 0, returns an Array of ascending length subarrays.

```
pyramid(0) => [ ]
pyramid(1) => [ [1] ]
pyramid(2) => [ [1], [1, 1] ]
pyramid(3) => [ [1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1] ]
```

the solution i wrote is :

```
List<List<int>> pyramid(int n) {
  List<List<int>> bigList = [];
  List<int> smallList = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //1: i==1, i==2
    smallList.add(1);
    // bigList.add([smallList]);   won't work because it takes only integers in parameters
    List<List<int>> fixedList = [smallList];
    print(fixedList);
    bigList.addAll([smallList]);
    print(bigList); // bigList,[[1]]
  }
  print(bigList);
  return bigList;
}

void main() {
  pyramid(3);
}
```

the output I get is not the one wanted, here is the output with the prints to know what happens in each iteration:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]
[[1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

My question is: (and I am looking to find my mistake not the right answer)I dont understand why at the end of  first iteration i=0, `bigList` has `[1]` as a first element. but has `[1,1]` as a first element in the end of the second iteration. why did the first element of `bigList` change. all I am doing is appending to the list. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<List<Object>> makePyramid(int n) {
  if (n < 1) return [];
  var result = List.generate(n, (i) => List.filled(i+1, 1));
  
  return result;
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  List.generate(4, (i) => i).forEach((e) => print(makePyramid(e)));
}
```

Output:

```
[]
[[1]]
[[1], [1, 1]]
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I did find as well as another tweak to mine to make it give the right result. However I need to understand why does my solution give the output it gives instead of the one I want it to. I am looking to know my mistake because I still don't see it